# Syntax highlighting for markdown can't be set manually

Tags: syntax-highlighting

If the file is named `*.markdown` then the highlighting works correctly.  If it is named `*.md` then it doesn't work.

Even if I type `:set syntax=markdown`, the highlighting doesn't turn on.

With other filetypes e.g. `awk`, I can turn on the highlighting by running `:set syntax=awk`.  But this doesn't work for markdown.

Ultimately I want to [make Vim recognize .md files as markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779012/5419599), but when the autocommand didn't work I tried just setting the syntax directly and found that didn't work either.

What could be causing this?

I am using [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/).

Comment: Does `:set filetype=markdown` help or is the filetype already set correctly?

Comment: @cbaumhardt, sorry, I should have mentioned: I tried both `set filetype=markdown` and `set syntax=markdown` and neither made any difference.

Comment: When I start my Vim 7.4 without my vimrc (`vim -Nu NONE`), write a small markdown example, enter `:set filetype=markdown` and `:syntax on` it works for me. Do you have syntax enabled? Are you using an old Vim version?

Comment: @cbaumhardt, I'm using 7.3.646.  I confirmed that doing what your comment suggested worked, and doing the same without the `-Nu NONE` did not work.  My `~/.vimrc` includes [these lines](https://github.com/atsaloli/cf3-tutorial/blob/b5ef5f9a4926d102cd04636b86c9f06464636f35/source/100-180-Installing_Syntax_Highlighter-0265-Install_Vim_Plugin.sh#L10-L45) for editing CFEngine files, then at the bottom I have `set smartindent`, `filetype plugin indent on`, `syntax on` which may be redundant but I was trying to get something else to work...any of these look like a likely culprit?

Comment: Does `:syntax on` have no effect? At least you now know that it is related to your `.vimrc`. You can try to comment out blocks of code to figure out what causes this behaviour. The lines you linked don't look relevant to me.

Comment: @cbaumhardt, I tried this again—even with `-Nu NONE` I can't get an *existing* markdown file to have syntax highlighting, only a new one.  So it's not the `.vimrc` after all.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: As noted by @Christian Brabandt below, **this is no longer the case**. Can't imagine why I had to do this. :=(

You have to `:set filetype=markdown` or do it in an autocmd group.

Turns out that vim by default sets `.md` files to Modula-2 (except for README.md), so that overrides the syntax setting.

Comment: That is not correct. Vims default for `.md` files is markdown as can be seen [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/filetype.vim#L959). This has been changed like 5 years ago.